# Session Cache is not configured - Ubuntu 12.04.5 Apache 2.4.12 TLSv1.2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to use move my iOS app to use TLS1.2, as is required by Swift2. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5 and in order to have the TLSv1.2 protocol as an option, I had to update my Apache to 2.4.12.

I used this tutorial to do so: http://www.ivankrizsan.se/2014/07/17/upgrading-apache-http-server-2-2-to-2-4-on-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-520

Now, port 443 is running.

However, I am not able to connect using ssl and my error log displays: 
Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

Any ideas about how to solve this would be appreciated.

R

Comment: You might want to ask on http://askubuntu.com instead as this doesn't seem to be related to programming directly.

Comment: Oh thanks @SaeX - I'll give that a shot -